# Time operations on a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

For this dataframe I'm trying for each value `id2` of the column **Id** calculate the difference of time betweeen the previous and following row with id value `id1`. Then keep just the closest row in term of time.

```
  Id         time              value

  id1        14:07:53.158      1
  id2        14:07:53.358      2
  id1        14:07:54.462      3
  id1        14:10:09.560      4
  id2        14:10:10.160      5
  id1        14:10:10.520      6
```

Comment: is your pattern always of the form id1 id2 id1, then repeat?

Comment: @boud yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build previous and next time deltas:

```
df['prev'] = (df.time.shift(-1) - df.time)[::3]

df['next'] = (df.time - df.time.shift(1))[2::3]
df['next'] = (df.time - df.time.shift(1))[2::3]

df
Id  time    value   prev    next
0   id1 2018-04-18 14:07:53.158 1   00:00:00.200000 NaT
1   id2 2018-04-18 14:07:53.358 2   NaT NaT
2   id1 2018-04-18 14:07:54.462 3   NaT 00:00:01.104000
3   id1 2018-04-18 14:10:09.560 4   00:00:00.600000 NaT
4   id2 2018-04-18 14:10:10.160 5   NaT NaT
5   id1 2018-04-18 14:10:10.520 6   NaT 00:00:00.360000
```

Then fill the NAs and calculate the smallest timedelta:

```
df.prev = df.prev.ffill()
df.next = df.next.bfill()

df['keep'] = df.prev < df.next

df
df
Id  time    value   prev    next    keep
0   id1 2018-04-18 14:07:53.158 1   00:00:00.200000 00:00:01.104000 True
1   id2 2018-04-18 14:07:53.358 2   00:00:00.200000 00:00:01.104000 True
2   id1 2018-04-18 14:07:54.462 3   00:00:00.200000 00:00:01.104000 True
3   id1 2018-04-18 14:10:09.560 4   00:00:00.600000 00:00:00.360000 False
4   id2 2018-04-18 14:10:10.160 5   00:00:00.600000 00:00:00.360000 False
5   id1 2018-04-18 14:10:10.520 6   00:00:00.600000 00:00:00.360000 False
```

Now filter the results based on the following criteria: keep id2 rows, as well as each row modulo 3 = 0 where keep is True, or modulo 3 = 2 where keep is False:

```
df[((df.Id=='id2') | ((df.index%3==0) & df.keep) | ((df.index%3==2) & ~df.keep))]

Id  time    value   prev    next    keep
0   id1 2018-04-18 14:07:53.158 1   00:00:00.200000 00:00:01.104000 True
1   id2 2018-04-18 14:07:53.358 2   00:00:00.200000 00:00:01.104000 True
4   id2 2018-04-18 14:10:10.160 5   00:00:00.600000 00:00:00.360000 False
5   id1 2018-04-18 14:10:10.520 6   00:00:00.600000 00:00:00.360000 False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
# convert time column to timedelta
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

# create dictionary of results, with keys as df index
d = {i+1: df['time'].iloc[i+2] - df['time'].iloc[i] for i in range(0, len(df.index), 3)}

# map differences to dataframe
df['difference'] = df.index.map(d.get)

# filter for lowest time
res = df[df['difference'] == df['difference'].min()]

print(res)

#     Id            time  value      difference
# 4  id2 14:10:10.160000      5 00:00:00.960000
```